# How to prettify programming language

Tags: language-agnostic, prettify

I have code written in any programming language. How can I "prettify" it (bold if, else etc.) to display on a website? Are there any good APIs to do that?

Comment: Could you specify, are you coding in an IDE? If so, they already have options to do that. For example, in Eclipse, you can choose a color scheme and make certain types of key words (like conditions) bold, italicized, etc.

Comment: Do you mean syntax highlighting in an editor, or for export as, say, HTML with the markup?

Comment: No, I will have a website where this code should be prettified.

Comment: Do you at least have a hint what the language is?

Comment: This question about Google Prettify should help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667097/how-to-get-google-prettify-to-render-more-like-visual-studio

Comment: But what I mean is, will the user give you a hint what the language is? Language detection is another topic

Comment: Language detection could be pretty difficult. It would be better if the user specify it (like in [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/)).

Comment: Yes, user would tell me what language it would be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is [Google's prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/) which is widely used for such tasks (e.g. SO itself [uses](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/79591/167396) it for highlighting of code).

> Google Code Prettify JavaScript library supports all C-like (Java,
>   PHP, C#, etc), Bash-like, and XML-like languages without need to
>   specify the language and has customizable styles via CSS.

Moreover, as i know, there is a lot of third-party styles for those languages that not supported officially.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using PHP, I recommend [GeSHi](http://qbnz.com/highlighter/)

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about an auto-formatter, I've used PEAR's [PHP Beautifer](http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_Beautifier/redirected) before.

Although you shouldn't really need a script to format your code for you...

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/) is the most common plugin used on the web I think.

I think it works for most programming languages.

I see it everywhere. I am actually thinking of adding it to my website as well.